# What are Android different screens dimensions in dp for different screens (e.g. xlarge = 960dp x 720dp)?

Tags: android, size, dimensions, screens

In [Range of screens supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range), the Android team mentioned that:

> As you design your UI for different screen sizes, you'll discover that each design requires a minimum amount of space. So, each generalized screen size above has an associated minimum resolution that's defined by the system. These minimum sizes are in "dp" units—the same units you should use when defining your layouts—which allows the system to avoid worrying about changes in screen density.
>
> - xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> - large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> - normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> - small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

So, If I want to support all Android screens:

1. Can I create images, for full screen view, in those dimensions and that will be sufficient condition to support all available screens?
2. Or they are just the minimum sizes, and I need other dimensions?
3. If other dimensions are needed, what are they? in other way, what are the dimensions I should ask the graphics designer to provide me with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They are just the minimum sizes. Manufacturers can make screen with any size they want, theoretically.

Comment: Thanks. If you've read the whole topic, you will see that approximate generalized sizes can be used, and Android will automatically do the needed scaling for the not existing dimensions. So, do you know what are those intermediate dimensions that can be used to support all the screens?

Comment: They depend on vendor. And theoretically can be any size, so I think there is no any intermediate dimension list at all.

Comment: -1 I know this is quite old now, but I happened across it and your answer really should've been a comment IMO, since it adds some information but doesn't really answer the questions.